# MYSQL select same column name as alias in union not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple MYSQL query that unions two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT col1 AS col1A FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT col1 AS col1B FROM table2
) AS t WHERE col1A <> col1B
```

I have a column called `col1` in both tables and I need to select only rows that have a different value of that column so I select them as aliases. When I run this query I got:

```
Unknown column 'col1B' in 'where clause'
```

Table1 data:

```
col1
----
test
```

Table2 data:

```
col1
----
test
```

The query should return no rows as each value in col1 in table1 is equal to each value in col1 in table2 instead it returns that col1 in table2 is unknown although I select it as an alias

Comment: What do you want the output to be? If you execute the `UNION` inner query only, you'll see where this went wrong. The `UNION` returns only one column and it is known as `col1A` (though it contains the values of also what you called `col1B`)

Comment: If you post a small sample of the rows from each table together with what output you hope to get from that sample, we can help you sort this out.

Comment: why not be specific and use: `WHERE table1.col1 <> table2.col1`

Comment: @TarynEast tried that but it still gave the same error

Comment: I'm afraid you should read `XY Problem` http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: @MichaelSamuel - You need to step back a bit and re-evaluate what you are asking here.  Union won't work for what you are trying to do (aliasing a column in a union statement's second select and expecting a column with that alias shows that you do not understand what a union statement is). step back and try to describe what you are trying to accomplish.  Do you think union and 'merge tables' are the same thing by any chance?

Comment: Voting to close as it is still unclear what OP is asking.  The answer to the question you asked is you are using `UNION` incorrectly.  There are several comments about why (including my posted answer)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why Error 1054 is being returned by OP query**

The error that's being returned is because the name assigned to a column from the result of a UNION is taken from the first SELECT.

You can observe this by running a simple example:

```
 SELECT 1 AS one 
  UNION
 SELECT 2 AS two
```

The resultset returned by that query will contain a single column, the name assigned to the column will be `one`, the column name from the first SELECT. This explains why you are getting the error from your query.

---

**One way to return rows with no match**

To return values of `col1` from `table1` which do not match any value in the `col1` column from `table2`...

one option to use an anti-join pattern...

```
    SELECT t1.col1
      FROM table1 t1
      LEFT
      JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
     WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` operation returns *all* rows from table1, along with any "matching" rows found in table2. The "trick" is the predicate in the WHERE clause... any "matching" rows from table2 will have a non-NULL value in col1. So, if we exclude all of the rows where we found a match, we're left with rows from table1 that didn't have a match.

If we want to get rows from `table2` that don't have a "matching" row in `table1`, we can do the same thing, just flipping the order of the tables.

If we combine the two sets, but only want a "distinct" list of "not matched" values, we can use the `UNION` set operator:

```
    SELECT t1.col1
      FROM table1 t1
      LEFT
      JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
     WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL
     UNION 
    SELECT s2.col1
      FROM table2 s2
      LEFT
      JOIN table1 s1
        ON s1.col1 = s2.col1
     WHERE s1.col1 IS NULL
```

--

**Finding out which table the non-matched value is from**

Sometimes, we want to know which query returned the value; we can get that by including a literal value as a discriminator in each query.

```
    SELECT 'table1' AS src
         , t1.col1
      FROM table1 t1
      LEFT
      JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
     WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL
     UNION 
    SELECT 'table2' AS src
         , s2.col1
      FROM table2 s2
      LEFT
      JOIN table1 s1
        ON s1.col1 = s2.col1
     WHERE s1.col1 IS NULL
    ORDER BY 2
```

---

**A different (usually less performant) approach to finding non-matching rows**

An entirely different approach, to returning an equivalent result, would be do something like this:

```
SELECT q.col1
  FROM ( SELECT 't1' AS src, t1.col1 FROM table1 t1 
          UNION
         SELECT 't2' AS src, t2.col1 FROM table2 t2
       ) q
 GROUP BY q.col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT q.src) < 2
ORDER BY q.col1
```

(The inline view `q` will be "materialized" as a derived table, so this approach can be expensive for large sets, and this approach won't take advantage of indexes on `col1` to perform the matching.) One other small difference between this and the anti-join approach: this will omit a col1 value of NULL if a NULL exists in both tables. Aside from that, the resultset is equivalent.

Comment: thanks but I already know the left join :) I want the results from both tables to be returned in separate rows so join won't work in my case so i have to union

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: I'm missing the point you are making. The query I provided returns each "not matched" value on separate rows. None of the rows returned from the anti-join will have values from "both rows". Your reasoning for "i have to union" is obtuse. (Obviously, you're free to use `UNION` in whatever query you want, and you should, since you "have to union".)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel - no you don't...a union will not accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: The 3rd and 4th queries will suit your needs.  You need both the JOIN and UNION.

Comment: @simo.379209: An anti-join result can also be obtained using a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subqery)`, as demonstrated in the answer from sgeddes.

Comment: @spencer7593 - yeah I thought that initially too, but OP wants the records from table2 as well that aren't in table1. sgeddes query doesn't do this part.  It could be extended to do that part by UNIONing with the 'reverse'.  I like your 3rd query as I think it does what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @simo.379209: It sounds like the OP specification would be met with a **`FULL OUTER anti-join`**; but since MySQL doesn't support the **full** outer join operation,  we have to workaround that limitation, we use a `UNION` set operator to emulate that; we obtain an equivalent result with the **`anti-join UNION anti-join`** pattern, as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: @spencer7593 hey mate :) thanks for the clear explanation of the problem. I really appreciate that you explained the problem without arguing or being rude like others here! Sorry for the late reply. A union with a join were necessary as you explained and i finally achieved it...thanks very very much ;)

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to look up the appropriate usage of `UNION`.  It will return all results from first query combined with all results from the second query.  This results in a single dataset, with a single column (not col1 and col2), just col1 in this case.

Assuming you're trying to get all records in table1 that don't exist in table2, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT col1 
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1
    )
```

Comment: No i don't just want rows that exist in one and not exists in other. This is just simplified to pinpoint the problem. I want multiple where conditions and this is one of them

Comment: @MichaelSamuel -- you really need to update your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish.  Obviously we're having a lot of trouble understanding your requirements.  Try using sample data (more than 1 row per table) and desired results.  Perhaps better, build a sqlfiddle.com that demonstrates where you're having problems!  This does appear to  answer your question as it is currently written though.

Comment: my requirement is simple, i need to understand what's wrong with the syntax i posted. it's not about usage. I want to figure out what's wrong with the posted code. why mysql assumes that column is unknown

Comment: @MichaelSamuel - it assumes it's unknown because you are not using union correctly...answers here are acknowledging you are using it incorrectly and giving you alternatives based on a little guess work of what your requirements are.